# How to make each tweet on its own line?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am wanting to have each tweet be on its own line.

Currently, this breaks at each response (I listed Response_1...I am using through Response_10)

Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import json

response_1 = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=microsoft&page=1")
for i in response_1:
    print (i, "\n")
```

Comment: Why don't you use `tweepy`, `twitter` or `python-twitter` packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the json as a python object first, only then you can iterate over it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                              

import urllib
import json

response_1 = json.loads(urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=microsoft&page=1").read())
for i in response_1['results']:
    print (i, "\n")
```